# How to pass dynamic values to EventHub attribute Azure Function c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

The function trigger is of type `HttpTrigger` and I want the send data to `EventHub` outputEventHubMessage.

```
public class AzureTestFunc 
{
    private readonly ConfigSettings _settings;
    public AzureTestFunc(IOptions<ConfigSettings> options)
    {
        _settings = options.Value;
    }

     [FunctionName("test")]
     public HttpResponseMessage Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get","post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
     [EventHub("eventhubname-test", Connection = "connectionstring-test")] out string outputEventHubMessage, ILogger log, ExecutionContext ctx) 
     {
                
            return new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                Content = new StringContent(validationError)

            };
      }
    
}
```

How I can pass EventHubName and the Connection string values dynamically using `_settings` object in `[EventHub(?, ?)]` attribute?
`_settings` object is containing the values of EventHubName and Connection e.g. `_settings.EventHubName` & `_settings.Connection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For EventHubName, use "%YourEventHubSettingName%" format to pull in from appsettings.

For Connection, just give the name of the appsetting containing the  connectionstring, without the %'s.

Reference: [EventHub trigger binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#attributes)